# Save/Restore Ruby's Random

Tags: ruby, random

I'm trying to create a game, which I want to always run the same given the same seed. That means that random events - be them what they may - will always be the same for two players using the same seed.
However, given the user's ability to save and load the game, Ruby's Random would reset every time the save loaded, making the whole principle void if two players save and load at different points.

The only solution I have imagined for this is, whenever a save file is loaded, to generate the same number of points as before, and thus getting Ruby's Random to the same state as it was before load. However, to do that I'd need to extend it so a counter is updated every time a random number is generated.

Does anyone know how to do that or has a better way to restore the state of Ruby's Random?

PS: I cannot use an instance of Random (Random.new) and Marshall it. I have to use Ruby's default.

Comment: I'd think your problem is not just resuming a sequence of pseudo random numbers, but more generally of resuming a game where it left off. Suppose, for example, a power failure occurred, requiring that play be resumed from the last saved state. That suggests the need to save frequently and to use a database to commit transactions. Part of that would be for the server to maintain a single sequence of random numbers in a table, where each player would have a moving pointer into the table. If a user's pointer reached the end, the server would extend the table.

Comment: Cary, very valid concerns. But it is a standalone game,  no server involved. I just want players to be able to share seeds and experience the same things. Following your example, if there was a power failure,  the player would simply restore his last savespot and everything would happen the same way.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to use Ruby's default"?

Comment: steenlag: i want to change Ruby's Random::DEFAULT, which is used for things like array.sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [Marshal.dump/Marshal.load](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Marshal.html) may be exactly what you want.  The `Random` class [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Random.html) explicitly states "Random objects can be marshaled, allowing sequences to be saved and resumed."

You may still have problems with synchronization across games, since different user-based decisions can take you through different logic paths and thus use the sequence of random numbers in entirely different ways.

Comment: That would be perfect; however, that does not allow me to Marshal the root Random::DEFAULT, which is used for things like array.sample.

Concerning player action: yes, I know that player action will change the whole thing, but that allows two players to start from the same setup.

Comment: @Proto That ought not to be a problem.  Array's `sample` and `shuffle` methods [permit you to specify the rng](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest maybe saving the 'current' data to a file when the user decides to save (or when the program closes) depending on what you prefer.

This can be done using the [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html) class in ruby.

This would mean you'd need to keep track of turns and pass that along with the save data. Or you could loop through the data in the file and find out how many turns have occurred that way I suppose.

So you'd have something like:

```
def loadGame(loadFile)

    loadFile.open
    data = loadFile.read
    # What you do below here depends on how you decide to store the data in saveGame.

end

def saveGame(saveFile)

    saveFile.open
    saveFile.puts data
end
```

Havent really tried the above code so it could be bad syntax or such. It's mainly just the concept I'm trying to get across.

Hopefully that helps?

Answer (score 0):

There are many generators that compute each random number in the sequence from the previous value alone, so if you used one of those you need only save the last random number as part of the state of the game. An example is a basic [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which has the form:

```
z(n+1) = (az(n) + b) mod c
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are typically large (known) constants, and `z(0)` is the seed.

An arguably better one is the so-called "[mulitply-with-carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry#Comparisons_with_linear_congruential_generators)" method.